# Unable to understand this Template parameter

Tags: c++, function-pointers, template-meta-programming

Maybe it's flu, or I'm just plain stupid, but I can't understand a part of [this](https://github.com/ipkn/crow/blob/master/include/http_connection.h) Crow framework code. My inner C++ parser fails.

```
template <typename MW>
struct check_before_handle_arity_3_const
{
 template <typename T,
     //this line
     void (T::*)(int, typename MW::context&) const = &T::before_handle 
  >
    struct get
    { };
};
```

I know it's a template parameter inside template declaration. It looks like maybe some lambda  or function pointer type parameter... but, I'm not sure. 
Can someone explain this line?

**Update:**
Exploring depths of newly obtained knowledge - after the answer was given - led me to this excerpt from a great [book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_C%2B%2B_Design):

> A template can accept a pointer to a function as a nontype template
>   parameter. (Most often in this book, nontype template parameters are
>   integral values.) [...] Using a pointer to a function as a nontype
>   template argument means that we no longer need to store it in the map.
>   This essential aspect needs thorough understanding. The reason we
>   don't need to store the pointer to a function is that the compiler has
>   static knowledge about it. Thus, the compiler can hardcode the
>   function address in the trampoline code.

So, now I know one of the reasons to use this technique.

Comment: It's a member function pointer of `T`. You forgot to ask a question BTW.

Comment: My English grammar parser fails to see a question mark. What's your question? Whether this is C++? Whether it's killing you?

Comment: does this update qualifies as a question?

Comment: Almost. It's a yes/no question now and the answer is yes.

Comment: It's a template non-type parameter of type "pointer to member function of `T`" where the function type is "`void (int, typename MW::context&) const`".

Comment: and it have default value? (&T::before_handle)?

Comment: @strangeqargo What specifically don't you understand?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it was whole line, now I'm almost got it, enough for experimenting / googling, I guess

Comment: thank you all, guys

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`void (T::*)(int, typename MW::context&) const` is a non-type [template parameter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters).
It is a pointer to a member function of `T`.

With the use of `= &T::before_handle`, its default value is set to `&T::before_handle`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason I used this technique is to support 2 kinds of handler format:
https://github.com/ipkn/crow/blob/master/include/middleware.h#L17

`check_before_handle_arity_3_const` is used here:

```
    template <typename T>
    struct is_before_handle_arity_3_impl
    {
        template <typename C>
        static std::true_type f(typename check_before_handle_arity_3_const<T>::template get<C>*);

        template <typename C>
        static std::true_type f(typename check_before_handle_arity_3<T>::template get<C>*);

        template <typename C>
        static std::false_type f(...);

    public:
        static const bool value = decltype(f<T>(nullptr))::value;
    };
```

With SFINAE, `is_before_handle_arity_3_impl<T>::value` is determined whether we can call the handler with 3 arguments or not. By using `std::enable_if`, Crow can call the proper handler:
https://github.com/ipkn/crow/blob/master/include/http_connection.h#L110